# How do I make one object glide to the same position as another object with logic bricks?

Tags: game-engine

I'm currently in the process of learning BGE and was trying to make a board game. The idea is that once a player picks a square on the board the object should be able to glide to that part of the board...I've went under the assumption that the easiest way to do this would be to make the piece steer towards the target object then keep moving until it hits the object. Can anyone show me how this is done?
It is a game that uses the same 8x8 board as chess with each piece being able to move 1 space per turn so I was curios if there was a way to make a piece glide a specific distance in a certain direction?

e.g - If I were to press 'W' my object's X position = X + 2

Thanks

Comment: Have the mouse move an empty, and on click, have your piece use the steering actuator set to seek to make to go to that empty's position. You can make only one piece movable at a time by having each one use a Boolean property for when it is selected. clicking on a piece could set that to true, and clicking on any other piece would set it to false.

Comment: Sounds like a workable solution, you should post that as an answer so people can up-vote/approve

Comment: I've understood the steering block although I'm still a little confused as to how I keep it moving, If I follow your instructions my click will make it move part of the way to the object but stop going in that direction once the user lets go of the left mouse button...how do I set it to keep going until it reaches the object?

Answer (score 1):

- Have an steering actuator pathfinding to object "Target".
- enable self-terminated at the actuator

When selecting a field

- Place the "Target" at the selected field.
- activate the steering actuator

The object will navigate to the object "target" until it reached it's position. Make sure the objects can intersect (target should be ghost or an empty).